# Sophisticated page parsing with Apache Nutch

Tags: nutch

I use Apache Nutch 2.3.1 with Elasticsearch 1.7 for crawling and indexing respectively. After completing all the necessary procedures the final content of the parsed page includes both the header and footer which sometimes result to slightly irrelevant searches.

I would like to configure Nutch to exclude the header and footer of a page from the content. There are some [open](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585) issues in Nutch's JIRA but all seem to refer to the Nutch 1.x branch. In addition, I have enabled the [boilerpipe](https://github.com/apache/nutch/pull/92) plugin but I did not notice any change in the quality of the content.

Is there any plugin or another way to perform more precise parsing?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [NUTCH-1870](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1870) which uses XPath to extract specific portions of the document, but it is also developed for Nutch 1.x. To be honest although the Nutch 2.x branch is in active development (and improved a lot over time) the 1.x versions are still more feature rich and a lot of the new contributions are focused on the 1.x branch.

I'm guessing this plugins wouldn't be to hard to port into Nutch 2.x, and we welcome every contribution.

Comment: Are there any plans to get it merged for a future release?